# Will Telerik Document Processing Library work with JavaScript?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, telerik

Right now I have an application that is currently using PrinceXML to make PDFs in our application, but we would like to move towards using Telerik as a solution.  The only problem I could foresee is that it expects all the rendering to be done on the markup prior to calling it.  For example, a form might have some JavaScript on the page that needs to run when the page loads to fully layout the form correctly.  If Telerik's component can't handle that (meaning the form has to be fully rendered server-side prior to) then that's going to be a problem.    I'm having a hard time finding documentation on whether the Telerik Document Processing Library handles this.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik offers another solution for client-side export, e.g.

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
<telerik:RadSkinManager ID="RadSkinManager1" runat="server" ShowChooser="true" />
<div class="demo-container size-medium">
    <div class="buttonsContainer">
        <telerik:RadButton RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" OnClientClicked="exportPDF" Text="Export page to PDF" AutoPostBack="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false"></telerik:RadButton>
        <telerik:RadButton RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" OnClientClicked="exportImage" Text="Export page to Image" AutoPostBack="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false"></telerik:RadButton>
        <telerik:RadButton RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" OnClientClicked="exportSVG" Text="Export page to SVG" AutoPostBack="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false"></telerik:RadButton>
    </div>
    <telerik:RadClientExportManager runat="server" ID="RadClientExportManager1">
    </telerik:RadClientExportManager>
</div>
<script>
    var $ = $telerik.$;

    function exportPDF() {
        $find('<%=RadClientExportManager1.ClientID%>').exportPDF($("#main"));
    }

    function exportImage() {
        $find('<%=RadClientExportManager1.ClientID%>').exportImage($("#main"));
    }

    function exportSVG() {
        $find('<%=RadClientExportManager1.ClientID%>').exportSVG($("#main"));
    }
</script>
```

Please take a look at the following demos:

- https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/client-export-manager/functionality/export-whole-pages/defaultcs.aspx
- https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pdf-export/index and https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pdf-export/page-layout